# How to make conditionally "sticky" footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make my footer "sticky" but the heights vary so can't use most of the methods I've found or flexbox. Is there any way to check with javascript how much space is under a div so I can add that much margin?

The html looks like this:

```
  <container>
     <header></header>
     <body><sometimes sub content></sub content></body>
     <footer></footer>
   </container>
```

Also tried putting the footer outside of the container, saw that in some solutions, but again they all require a fixed height.

Comment: It would be helpful for others to understand your question if you could add some of your HTML markup, and javascript code that you have so far.

Comment: It's not so much the space under a div, as it is the height of the footer, yes? I'm assuming your issue is that your footer is covering up content, right? If so, if your footer has no margin/padding, you can simply do a `$("body").css("margin-bottom", $("footer").height() + "px"`

Comment: No, on pages where there is not much content the footer is at the end of the content, which is in the middle of the screen. I want to get it to stick to the bottom of the window, but then on other pages where there is more content I want it under the content

Comment: @nick Ahh okay, that makes a lot more sense. Well you can check if `$(document).height() > $(window).height()`. That will tell you if the height of the content is longer than the viewport. If so, leave the footer where it is. If the doc height is `<=` the viewport height, add `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `$(document).height() > $(window).height()`. That will tell you if the height of the content is longer than the viewport. If so, leave the footer where it is. If the doc height is <= the viewport height, add make the footer sticky. Like so:

**To see the difference between sticky and non-sticky**, run the snippet below to have the footer at the bottom of the page. To view it where the footer is sticky, run the snippet in full screen mode (on the top right corner of the snippet output). You can also just run it in full screen mode and then shrink your browser size down - it recalculates on window resize.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  // if content height <= viewport height, make footer sticky
  // else leave footer at the bottom of the content. 
  $(".footer").toggleClass("sticky", $(document).height() <= $(window).height());
});
```

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555588;
  color: white;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre style="font-size: 16px;">
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
    content
</pre>
<div class="footer">foo foo foo <br/>foo<br/>foo<br/></div>
```

Comment: Whoa, weird! Why did it split my edits into a new post?

Comment: Regarding your mod flag, there is unfortunately very little we can do to help you here. While we can merge two *questions* (moving the answers from a dupe to a master, preserving their votes), we cannot merge two *answers*. I've no idea how your edits were split into a new post. They should not have been. If you are *certain* you did not inadvertently click "Add Another Answer", then you should post a bug report on [Meta]. Anyway, regarding the problem at hand, the only thing that can be done is deleting the old, obsolete answer. I've done that for you. Only 10 points lost; not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `main` minimum height to `100vh`, and position the footer at the bottom absolutely. The main should have bottom padding to at least the height of the footer, and `box-sizing: border-box` to main the `100vh` height.

However the example to see the sticky footer in action.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hidden {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}

main:not(:hover) > .hidden {
  display: none;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>Short Article</article>
  
  <article class="hidden">
    long article
  </article>
  
  <footer>
    I'm the footer
  </footer>
</main>
```