# Footer doesn't always stick to bottom

Tags: css, reactjs

I have been trying to set my footer in my web for a while with no luck.. 
The footer sticking to the bottom of the screen, and if there is scroll-bar, so when I scroll down, it will slide up... 
I want it to stick to the bottom but not like position: fixed (if there is scroll-bar, then I don't want to see the footer until I scroll to the bottom). 
There is 3 main components in my web (header, content and footer). 
This is the footer css:

```
background: #929191;
border-top: 1px black solid;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
```

I have tryed changing html and body to "height: 100%" but the only thing that was almost like I wished for, was when it made the height bigger than the screen. 
It was like height: 110% (even though the sum of heights was 100%). 
I Tryed to reduce it, until I fit but it every little change in the UI make troubles. 
I would very appreciate any help..

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467527/4987197) is what you are looking for

Comment: Do you know exactly how tall your footer is in pixels? If so, you can use height: calc(100% - footerheight) with footerheight being the pixel value.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I try it as I said in the main post.

Comment: @mhodges Thanks! I believe it shall work. Is there any way to it without javascript included?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda If i'll give bottom than 0, so it wont be at the bottom. I think I don't understand your solution

Comment: @MasterPiece [Here's a working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sov2omtw/)

Comment: @MasterPiece Not if you want it to function differently based on whether there is a scroll bar or not. CSS doesn't know anything about dynamic content height and you cannot put logic to determine if the content overflows the viewport height (AKA when a scrollbar appears). That has to be done in JavaScript. You can certainly do it without the jQuery that I have in my solution, but you can't cut out the JS completely

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `<footer>`. Keep in mind it won't work in early versions of Internet Explorer. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp) is some more information. Let me know if this works out.

Comment: It didn't work.. I want it to be at the bottom of the screen, not only below the container

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your footer -

```
.footer {
        position: relative;
        bottom:  -500px; // you can adjust the negative value
    }
```